# How do I exclude a term from an Exposed filter in Views?

Tags: views

So I'm creating a view that filters out content and only displays content as long as it has a specific value from a taxonomy selected.

So I want it to start with Sci-Fi, but the filter is exposed so you could check other genres. But I want scifi to be excluded from that display of terms when the filter is exposed.

I've never had much luck with the grouped filters, so any assistance on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I bet using jQuery you can accomplish this.

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm not someone I would trust to develop such a line of code for this.

There isn't a way in views to do this?